# Are there any self-driving cab services in India

Tags: india, bookings, driving

[Ola](https://www.olacabs.com) and [Uber](https://www.uber.com/en/in/) are the most-used cab services in India. But these cabs have a driver.

Are there any self-driving cab services available in India. I mean that the cab should not have any driver and it drives by itself.

Comment: Just FTR I'm pretty sure there is **not**.

Comment: Car rental services are provided by [Zoomcar](https://www.zoomcar.com/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are virtually no self-driving cab services anywhere in the world as of 2018 (edit: and in 2021).  Apart from an announced Waymo project in Phoenix AZ (USA) and the odd campus-style test, there simply isn't a full-fledged self-driving taxi available in any significant geographical area as of this writing.

Comment: There are also self-driving shuttle pods from the airport car parks to Heathrow Terminal 5, but they travel on their own roads rather than sharing them with other vehicles.

Comment: I’ve driven the latest Tesla “self driving” car and I can confirm you do not want to be in a driverless taxi for now. I’m sure it works well 99% of the time but the other 1% will kill you.